# How do I replace a block in the world

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I want to swap some blocks when I use an item, but I don't know how to get the world to use the setBlockState method from what I saw the World class is abstract and I'll have to implement a bunch of methods. Is there another method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the player's location, executing the respective calculations from the player's position to get the block which you want (providing you don't already have this location stored).
You can use the `Block.setType(Material material)` method under the Block object to set the block type.

```
public void swapBlock(Location location, Material newType){
    location.getBlock().setType(newType);
}
```

Comment: I don't have the setType method in my Blocks class is something that I have to add?(Im using 1.19.1)

Comment: Take a look at the Block documentation [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/Block.html), alternatively, look at the Location documentation [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Location.html).